# Stop Service Fabric Service if Health Report has Error

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

I'm doing some preliminary checks when a service starts and reporting a health error if necessary:

```
HealthInformation healthInformation = new HealthInformation("Source", "Some error", HealthState.Error);
context.ReportPartitionHealth(healthInformation);
```

What is the best way to stop a service if it's in an error state?

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen when you "stop" a service?

Comment: By stopping I mean that I don't want SF to try and restart the service on a different node when I know it to be in a fatal state. I will raise a fault instead of reporting bad health